# Can't get the right wrapping and squishing behavior with flexbox/grid

Tags: css, flexbox

Right now I have a flex row of multiple items that may squish as needed. Sort of like this:

```css
:root {
  color-scheme: dark;
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fff;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.container > div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #222;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Thing</div>
  <div>Another thing</div>
  <div>Nothing</div>
  <div>Thing 2: Electric Boogaloo</div>
  <div>Thing 3: Tokyo Drift</div>
</div>
```

This works great. But I want this to also work on smaller screens. If you use your browser console to squish the items, you'll see that they end up wrapping and overflowing. I want to fix this by allowing them to flow onto one extra row.

So first I tried flex-wrap, but that causes it to wrap as soon as it's too big, not doing any text wrapping at all, which makes too many rows.

Then I tried grid, and I got something sort-of-working by using grid with `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(5rem, auto)); grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto); grid-auto-flow: column;`. However, this breaks growing and shrinking (the items are all fixed widths and it doesn't go onto one line if there's space), and the items now go from top to bottom instead of left to right.

While I could do `@media` w/ grid-auto-flow or set `flex-basis` with JS, those don't have perfect behavior (media is just a guess of where it will wrap, flex-basis is just a guess of how long the text is). So is there a way to have flex/grid fill two rows equally?

Comment: You mean the second row divs should be the same width as the first row? Then flexbox in not the way. CSS-Grid is really your only option here other than JS

Comment: @Paulie_D nope, in fact having the second row's divs being the same width as the first row's is one of the problems I'm running in to when I tried to implement grid. I just want to somehow have one row, then if anything overflows put it into the next row, but not wrap more than 2 rows total. the items should stretch like they normally do with flex. if this is possible with grid it would be nice to have some pointers

Comment: You can't limit the number of rows without a specific height to the parent to determine when overflow should happen. Even then the height of the rows is likely to be unknown so Javascript would be required.

Comment: Setting a specific height doesn't help (it chops off all items instead of squishing them with flex, and doesn't do anything with grid)

Comment: Grid isn't going to help as you have discovered. The behaviour you want is not a CSS issue, it's more complex than that.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use Javascript to dynamically distribute your items between two flexboxes based on the length of content they contain, on narrow screens, and for wider screens put all items into a single flexbox.

```js
const thingsRaw = ['Thing', 'Another thing', 'Nothing', 'Thing 2: Electric Boogaloo', 'Thing 3: Tokyo Drift']
const delay = 50
const breakpoint = 620
let timeout = null

const things = []
let lastThing = null
thingsRaw.forEach(tr => {
  const thing = {data: tr, cumulativeLength: tr.length + (lastThing ? lastThing.cumulativeLength : 0)}
  things.push(thing)
  lastThing = thing
})

const totalLength = things[things.length - 1].cumulativeLength
const midPoint = totalLength / 2
let minDiffFromCentre = 99999
let minIndex = null
for (var i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
  const t = things[i]
  t.diffFromCentre = Math.abs(midPoint - t.cumulativeLength)
  if (t.diffFromCentre < minDiffFromCentre) {
    minDiffFromCentre = t.diffFromCentre
    minIndex = i 
  }
}

const buildHTML = a => {
  const s = ['<div>']
  a.forEach(t => {
    s.push(`<div>${t.data}</div>`)
  })
  s.push('</div>')
  return s.join('')
}

const repaint = () => {
  const s = []
  if (window.innerWidth < breakpoint) {
    s.push(buildHTML(things.slice(0,minIndex + 1)))
    s.push(buildHTML(things.slice(minIndex + 1)))
  }
  else s.push(buildHTML(things))

  document.querySelector('.container').innerHTML = s.join('')
}

window.addEventListener('resize', evt => {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(repaint, delay)
})

repaint()
```

```css
:root {
  color-scheme: dark;
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fff;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container>div {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
}

.container>div>div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #222;
  padding: 1em;
  height: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Make sure to use the **full page** link to test the responsiveness properly.